# How do I know an item is a directory while looping over zipfile in Python?

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

Doing something like this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

#open zip file
zipfile = ZipFile('Photo.zip')

#iterate zip contents
for zipinfo in zipfile.filelist:
    #do something
    filepath, filename = path.split(zipinfo.filename)
```

How do I know if `zipinfo` is a file or a directory?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably this is the right way:

```
is_dir = lambda zipinfo: zipinfo.filename.endswith('/')
```

Comment: I believe the directory separator is always normalised to `/` within a zip file, no matter which platform is was created on.

Comment: @Greg: my doubt was it was dependent by the platform the zip was **opened** but have no Windows box to test it.

Comment: No, there is no change. The path separator inside a zip file is always `/` no matter which platform it's opened on.

Comment: FYI, in zip files found in the wild, there will not always be a directory member where there are files inside that directory.  Sometimes only the file members will exist, without a separate member for the containing directory.

Comment: Oh, what a crock this module is.  If you print() a ZipInfo, it shows a "filemode".  There's no such member.

Answer (score 14):

Starting with Python 3.6 there is a `ZipInfo.is_dir()` method.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as archive:
    for file in archive.namelist():
        file_info = archive.getinfo(file)
        if file_info.is_dir():
            # do something
```

[See the Python 3.6 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.is_dir) for details.